# iOS object is identifying as wrong class

Tags: objective-c, ios

So long story short, I have some odd bugs in some code I'm messing with and it turns out that it comes from an object being identified as the wrong class.

Here is my code, with the NSLog statement I put before anything touches the object... I can't figure out why it's showing as the wrong class.

Photo.h

```
@interface Photo : NSObject
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *descr;

@end
```

Photo.m

```
@implementation Photo

@synthesize image;
@synthesize descr;

@end
```

CameraViewController.h

```
#include "Photo.h"

@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Photo *photo;

-(void)takePhoto;
-(void)resetImage;

@end
```

and finally...
CameraViewController.m

```
#import "Photo.h"
....

@implementation CameraViewController

@synthesize photo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([_photo class]));
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

This prints out:

```
UIImageView
```

I would expect it to print out

```
Photo
```

or at the very least

```
NSObject
```

Am I missing something???

Comment: Where are you making the assignment to the .photo property of the controller?

Comment: Why would it print `Photo`, if you have not assigned it?

Comment: You never define this variable at all....(You don't have a variable called "_photo" unless the above code is wrong)

Comment: @borrrden: The `@sythesize` statement creates a variable named with an underscore by default in the newest Apple LLVM compiler.

Comment: OK that's what I thought.... I've fixed my problem but this points to my original understanding.  If a variable is created of the type of that property, isn't that init'ing the variable?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, but he is overriding it with his own `@synthesize` if you notice ;).  Dan, yes it creates a variable but it doesn't initialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending an object the `class` message retrieves that object's *dynamic* type. The object must be assigned prior to querying it for its `class`. In other words, declaring a property as `Photo*` is not sufficient for its `class` to return `Photo`: you must also assign it an instance of `Photo` or one of its subclasses. In the later case, the result of sending `class` message will be different (i.e. the `Class` of the subclass will be returned).

Comment: Thank you... I thought that synthesizing basically did that.  I changed the code to alloc and init and it's working fine now.